# Is there a way how to disable spell checking for Word document in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I'm creating MS Word document using docx4j and in MS Word all texts are marked with spell checker as text is attributed as english but it is different language. Is there a way how to disable spell checking using docx4j or Apache POI?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that spell-check is a user preference, and has nothing to do with the document itself. As such, I believe the answer is a hard no.

Comment: hmm, and any other way how easily :-) define proper language for entire document?

Comment: Might be worth unzipping a docx file created through Word that has the appropriate language settings active and see if you can find the property for it

Comment: Apache POI has language style attribute for paragraphs. But I'm using docx4j because I'm creating file content from html files.  So basicly each text paragraph is created automaticly with html to docx xml converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclosure: I maintain docx4j**

When you use XHTMLImporter, you should be importing into a docx with suitable language settings.

Typically this is done in the styles part, **w:styles/w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault/w:rPr**:

```
<w:styles xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:docDefaults>
    <w:rPrDefault>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="ko-KR" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
      </w:rPr>
    </w:rPrDefault>
  </w:docDefaults>
```

This value will be effective unless overridden in a style, or in the direct formatting which some of the other answers discuss.

Also, in /word/settings.xml, check **w:themeFontLang**:

```
<w:settings xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >
  <w:themeFontLang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="ko-KR"/>
```

You can either maintain per-language templates, or you can use docx4j to alter these settings dynamically. If you want to do that and have any trouble, please post a separate question.

Regarding hiding spelling/grammar errors, assuming MainDocumentPart mdp:

```
DocumentSettingsPart dsp = mdp.getDocumentSettingsPart();
dsp.getContents().setHideGrammaticalErrors(new BooleanDefaultTrue());
dsp.getContents().setHideSpellingErrors(new BooleanDefaultTrue());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single place where you can turn off proofing for the entire document. Instead it must be turned off for each and every run in the document. You can do that with Apache POI, but you must use the CT classes as this property has not yet been surfaced. Here is one way you might go about it for a single run `r`.

```
public static void setNoProof (XWPFRun run) {
    CTR ctR = run.getCTR();
    CTRPr ctRPr = ctR.isSetRPr() ? ctR.getRPr() : ctR.addNewRPr();
    if (!ctRPr.isSetNoProof()) {
        // If the noProof property is missing, add it
        ctRPr.addNewNoProof();
    } else {
        // If the noProof property is present, make sure it is not
        // FALSE, OFF, or X_0
        CTOnOff noProof = ctRPr.getNoProof();
        if (noProof.isSetVal() &&
                (noProof.getVal() == STOnOff.FALSE ||
                noProof.getVal() == STOnOff.OFF ||
                noProof.getVal() == STOnOff.X_0)) {
            noProof.setVal(STOnOff.TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Now loop through your runs, and call this method for each run.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to "Hide spelling errors in this document only" and "Hide grammar errors in this document only". See [How to Temporarily Disable Spell Check in Word](http://johnlamansky.com/tech/disable-word-spell-check/).

Using XWPF (`*.docx`) the XML for this is contained in `/word/settings.xml` and looks like:

```
<w:settings ...>
...
 <w:hideSpellingErrors/>
 <w:hideGrammaticalErrors/>
...
</w:settings >
```

We can set this without creating the whole `XWPFWorkbook` using `OPCPackage`, `PackagePart` and `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` objects.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.SettingsDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSettings;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships.STRelationshipId;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class XWPFDisableSpellCheck {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  File file = new File("XWPFDisableSpellCheck.docx");
  OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

  PackagePart settingsPart = opcPackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/word/settings.xml")).get(0);

  SettingsDocument settingsDocument = SettingsDocument.Factory.parse(settingsPart.getInputStream());

  CTSettings settings = settingsDocument.getSettings();

  if (settings.getHideSpellingErrors() == null) settings.addNewHideSpellingErrors();
  if (settings.getHideGrammaticalErrors() == null) settings.addNewHideGrammaticalErrors();
  //settings.getHideSpellingErrors().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
  //settings.getHideGrammaticalErrors().setVal(STOnOff.ON);

  //create XmlOptions for saving the settings
  XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
  xmlOptions.setSaveOuter();
  xmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace();
  xmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces();
  xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  xmlOptions.setSaveSyntheticDocumentElement(new QName(CTSettings.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "settings"));
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(STRelationshipId.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "w");
  map.put(STRelationshipId.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "m");
  map.put(STRelationshipId.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "o");
  xmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(map);

  //save the settings
  OutputStream out = settingsPart.getOutputStream();
  settings.save(out, xmlOptions);
  out.close();

  opcPackage.close();

 }

}
```

After this code the options "Hide spelling errors in this document only" and "Hide grammar errors in this document only" are set in document `XWPFDisableSpellCheck.docx`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, POI can't reach that user preference. But you can change it yourself and use that document as a template for all future documents.

Comment: POI can indeed reach it, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info! It works, although is too inefficient for my needs as I am building reports that are <1000 pages long with <200,000 runs(because of customized table cell paragraph runs)